# como fazer uma DIV que aumente de tamanho sempre que aumentar o conteúdo?

Tags: html, css, css3

estou fazendo um trabalho do curso, preciso fazer uma DIV que aumente de tamanho de acordo com o conteúdo que eu adiciono. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Será que da certo se no css eu colocar assim:

height: ;

?

Tirando o valor.

Comment: Até aonde eu sei, a div já faz isso automaticamente.

Comment: `width: 100%;  ` no css do seu div.

Answer (score 1):

Depende, a div irá aumentar a largura ou Altura?

Você pode usar isso para largura:

```
min-width: 100px;
min-width: 500px;
```

Ou para altura:

```
min-height: 100px;
max-height: 500px;
```

você coloca um limite minimo para essa div e um limite máximo, pois quando você for colocando conteúdo dentro da div ela ir aumentado até um certo limite.

Answer (score 1):

Todas as `div's` possuem esse comportamento como padrão. Elas irão se ajustar conforme a necessidade.

O que você pode fazer, é definir o tamanho mínimo e máximo, como Romario Pires comentou. Isso irá lhe garantir um melhor controle de *layout*, sem "bagunçar" o seu site.

Qualquer outro `css` que você defina, irá substituir esse comportamento padrão da `div`. Veja esse meu exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/pz231z3L/2/

Digite qualquer texto que você deseja no `textarea` e observe como a `div` vai se adaptar ao seu texto. Sem a necessidade de nenhuma definição. A única coisa que ela possui é justamente o limite de `max-width` e `max-height`, para garantir que ela não ultrapasse esse espaço e bagunce o *layout* do site.

Agora uma observação importante, se a sua `div` não está com esse comportamento, provavelmente existe alguma propriedade/classe que está sobrescrevendo esse comportamento. Então recomendo que melhore sua pergunta e adicione o caso especifico que você deseja resolver.

Answer (score -2):

você deve usar as propriedades abaixo

height: auto;

width: auto;